# How to run javascript reduce function?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a javascript where i am taking the inner HTML from p tag by using its id and then apply a javascript function `reduce` over it such that if `index` belongs in `values` then span should have `word selected` as class
class and else if `index` not belongs in `values` then span should have only `word` as class

this is p tag

```
<p id="content">Sun rises in east</p>

const html_create_fn = () => {
    let values = ["2","3"]
    let sentence = document.getElementById("content") ? document.getElementById("content").innerHTML : null
    console.log(sentence);
    let words = sentence ? sentence.split(" ") : null
    console.log(words);

    if(words){
        document.getElementById("answer_content").innerHTML = words.reduce((acc, word, index) => {
            return `values.includes(${index+1}) ? ${acc}<span class="word selected" id=${index+1}>${word}</span> : ${acc}<span class="word" id=${index+1}>${word}</span>`;
        }, "");
    }
}
```

the desired output is like

```
<p><span class="word">Sun<span><span class="word selected">rises<span><span class="word selected">in<span><span class="word">east<span></p>
```

when the program runs the browser tab gets hanged and it does not work, I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you sure `reduce` is the correct choice here? Seems like you're just doing the equivalent to to `.map()` followed by `.join("")`.

Comment: At any rate, do you have any errors in the console? `array1` doesn't seem to be defined anywhere in this code, so maybe it throws an error.

Comment: @ThomasSablik good point. Missed that. Yes, that's not even evaluated.

Comment: Whats the desired outcome here? you want to wrap the 3rd and 4th word in a `span`?

Comment: Can you show what you are currently getting in console for words? We don't have the html input source so it is quite difficult to asses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're getting completely confused with the string interpolation inside your `reduce` function. Also, the `values` array needs to be numeric if you're looking for it with `index`.

This (I think) does what you're trying to do

```js
const html_create_fn = () => {
    let values = [3,4]
    let sentence = document.getElementById("content") ? document.getElementById("content").innerHTML : null
    console.log(sentence);
    let words = sentence ? sentence.split(" ") : null
    console.log(words);

    if(words){
        document.getElementById("answer_content").innerHTML = words.reduce((acc, word, index) => {
            return acc + (values.includes(index) ? `<span class="word selected" id=${index+1}>${word}</span>` : `<span class="word" id=${index+1}>${word}</span>`);
        }, "");
    }
}
html_create_fn()
```

```css
span.word {
  border:1px solid blue
}

span.word.selected{
  background-color:yellow
}
```

```html
<div id="content">Hello world foo bar bash bang</div>
<div id="answer_content"></div>
```

Comment: @PURU sorry I don't understand - are you asking a question?

Comment: Thanks @Jamiec  i was just asking that what wrong was I doing in my solution?

Comment: @PURU your reduce function was wrong. the `values.includes(...)` part was in the string.